# WebSocket connection to 'ws://' ipAddress '' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: javascript, websocket, glassfish

I'm using Glassfish 4.1 for my server with a Javascript client. Everything works locally, but when I try to connect to my remote server I get the error in the title.

This is the code I use to connect. Let me know if you need any other info.

```
if(window.location.protocol == "http:"){
    Echo.connect("ws://" + whereToConnect);
} 
else{
    Echo.connect("wss://" + whereToConnect);
}
```

Thanks.